# Position Div in the same location on images with different widths

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

There is a class where I want to place images. Within this class I introduce an image and within the image I intend to introduce a div.

When the image occupies the whole class, the div is well positioned, but when the image does not occupy the full width, the div shifts and does not behave responsively :(

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

**Image Problem**

[image]

Image not occupying width ... div shifts out of image.

[My code ---> Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qaeato?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

You can see the code used and test with different width image.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="drop" >
          <div class="abc">
            <!-- <img class="img-fluid Images" src="https://i.ibb.co/mqnwwKB/Screenshot-72.jpg"> -->
            <img class="img-fluid Images" src="https://i.ibb.co/3p3D4h6/dmitry-bayer-276d-F1-RG67-Q-unsplash.jpg">
        <div class="row boxImage">
            <div class="row divBtn">
                <a class="toggle-one">
                    <span class="nav-link btnZ"></span>
                  </a>
                <a class="toggle-two">
                  <span class="nav-link btnT"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="toggle-three">
                  <span class="nav-link btnR"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="toggle-four">
                  <span class="nav-link btnP"></span>
                </a>
             </div>
          <ul class="list-inline rating-list" *ngFor="let star of stars" style="display: inline-block">
            <li (click)="countStar(star)" [ngClass]="{'selected': (star <= selectedValue)}">
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.drop {
    margin-left: 25px;
    width: 90%;
  height: 696px;
    /* border: 3px dashed #DADFE3; */
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    /* margin: auto; */
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

      .boxImage{
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        background-position: 13px 13px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 50px;
        width: 44%;
        border-radius: 8px;
        opacity: 1;
        top: 91%;
        left: 43%;
      }

   .abc {
   /* width: 100% !important; */
    height: 100%;
}



.abc img {
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Is the stackblitz supposed to show the problematic case? When I run it, the div does not shift out of the image.

Comment: @ConnorsFan 
I already managed to solve this problem. The main problem is that I can't fix the div in the lower right corner on all images having these different widths. Example if uncomment in html and test with this image, the div goes to the center of the image, I want this div to be in the lower right corner, in all images

Answer (score 1):

you can make of **flex** and **max-width** for making it responsive.

```
  .boxImage {
        flex: 1 1 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        background-position: 13px 13px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 50px;
        width: 44%;
        border-radius: 8px;
        opacity: 1;
        top: 91%;
        left: 43%;
        max-width: 250px;
      }
```

Demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkz7zh

Comment: It worked, but is there a way to position the div in the lower right corner on all images, even though they have different widths? If you uncomment the other image in html, you can see that the div is in the center. Is there a way to always position it in the same place? (bottom right corner)

Comment: may be you need to make of use responsive frameworks like boostrap or material css. otherwise you need to write media queries to handle it. you can check this - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp.  But handling this with different image widths is kind of hacky.  try to have images with same width.